# Translating Kotlin algorithm into Java code

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin, android-camerax

Im pretty new at programming and i am struggling to implement the cameraX analyzer https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/camerax-getting-started/#7 .

Can someone help convert this line of code `val pixels = data.map { it.toInt() and 0xFF }` to Java.

Ps. the variable data is a byte array.

Comment: see if this works https://stackoverflow.com/a/6057546/8528047
if I'm not wrong the comments there say that a byte array is being converted to int array so you could have just googled how to do that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Map](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/map.html) does nothing else than just applying an operation `toInt() and 0xFF` to every element `it` of a sequence `data`.

```
int[] pixels = new int[data.length];
for(int i=0; i < data.length; i++){
    pixels[i] = (data[i] & 0xFF);
}
```